# Unable to read file contents in react-native >0.59

Tags: react-native, file-upload, react-native-fs, rn-fetch-blob

I want to upload documents in my react native app and for that I am using [react-native-document-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-document-picker)

But to read the base64 content of the file [react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs) is needed which has a dependency issue (needs react-native v0.59)

I am unable to install it, as I have react-native v 0.63

Getting the following error as I install it:

```
admin@Salvis-MacBook project % npm install react-native-fs --save
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: project@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react-native@0.63.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"0.63.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native@"^0.59.5" from react-native-fs@2.16.6
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-fs
npm ERR!   react-native-fs@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/admin/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/admin/.npm/_logs/2021-01-25T09_41_08_842Z-debug.log
```

Please suggest something if you ran onto the same issue.

I tried reading contents using [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) and it's working fine on Android but I am unable to read file in ios simulator (I downloaded some sample pdf file from safari)

Whenever I try to read the file, it says file not found.

I have also tried below methods:

```
uri.replace('file://', '')
uri.replace('file:', '')
decodeURIComponent(uri)
```

but still unable to read it on ios

Comment: Can you please tell us which type of error you are getting when you install it ?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the error

Comment: @KishanBharda do you have any solution?

Comment: I have, but It may not perfect solution. Try installing by running `npm install react-native-fs --save --legacy-peer-deps` command. This may not safe way but work around solution. There is an issue opened on library git repository. [check this](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/956)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is an issue with react-native-fs (there is an open issue: [check here](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/956))

So I found an alternate solution to read to contents(base64) of a file.
Just use the `readFile()` function of [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) instead.

In your function where you need to pass the base64 string, just do:

```
const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
let Base64String = await fs.readFile(yourFileObject.uri, 'base64');
```

`yourFileObject` is the object you get when you pick any file through react-native-document-picker

You can use any picker of your choice, just you need to pass the file uri(local path) in the `readFile()` function and you are ready to roll.

Comment: Does fetching it as a blob like this use a lot more memory?

Comment: I did not find any problem related to memory usage @kojow7